# Do nematodes have organ-level organisation?

Tags: anatomy

Some introductory biology books state that nematodes have a pseudocoelom. So, they have a false body cavity. So, does it also mean that they have organ level body organisation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Fig.1 is shown the body plan of a round worm:

[image: nematode]
<sup>Fig. 1. Nematode. source: [University of Illinois](http://www.uic.edu/classes/bios/bios100/labs/animaldiversity.htm)</sup>

You ask whether there is an organization in terms of organs; an **[organ](http://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Organ)** is:

> A group of tissues that perform a specific function or group of functions;

A **[tissue](http://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Tissue)** is:

> An aggregate of cells in an organism that have similar structure and function;

As you can see in Fig. 1, there are clearly organs present, including a mouth, pharynx, reproductive organs, among others. They fulfill different tasks and contain various tissues, each dedicated to specific functions. Hence, they fulfill the definitional requirement of being *organs*.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Christiaan's answer, I quote Caenorhabditis elegans' anatomy to substantiate that nematode have proper organ development.

[image]